# Apache Webserver access to External Harddrive on Windows

Tags: windows, apache, webserver

how can I access external USB drive from webserver, where the webroot is C:\xampp\htdocs\192.168.1.101\ and the external hdd is F:\

this is my config i have tried:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin damn@mail.com
    DocumentRoot "C:/WebServer/htdocs/192.168.1.101"
    ServerName local.mydomain.org
    ServerAlias local.mydomain.org
    ErrorLog "logs/local-101-error.log"
    CustomLog "logs/local-101-access.log" common

    Alias "/extern" "F:/"
    <Directory F:/>
        Options +Indexes
    </Directory>

</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: And, what happened when you tried that?

Comment: Error 403 ... Access Denied

Comment: Aha, so the issue is _not_ the integration, but most likely the file system permissions.

Comment: I'm not good in Apache config, I'm always working on Linux with Lighty... Is the alias and directory config ok?

Comment: Looks like, I would expect another error message otherwise: startup errors or maybe an internal error. But a 403 indicates things are working, but the http server fails to access _content_ in the file system.

Comment: I'm running Win XP on my little Home Server with XAMPP, the F:/ Drive is an USB drive... I can Access it from Network (SMB/DLNA/NFS) without problems. Under Linux i would create an Symbolic Link in the web folder.. but have no idea how to do it under windows

Comment: MS-Windows does not support symbolic links in the file system. Your approach is correct, but as said: most likely the file system permissions do not grant the http server to access that file system. You want to check both, the actual account and the file system permissions.

Comment: just have seen inthe logs: [date] [authz_core:error] [pid...] [client ip:port] AH01630: client denied by server configuration: F:/

Comment: Ah, that means your default access rules prevent any access. Ok, so allow access. In newer apache version that would be `Require all granted`.

Comment: Thank you very much! It works! I have added to the Directory following options: AllowOverride All, Order Allow,Deny, Allow from all, Require all granted. I Think "Require all granted" only shoult work too. Thanky again!